# ROXTerm became invisible after intel drivers update

Tags: debian, kde, intel-graphics, vulkan

I installed some newer graphics drivers [following this guide](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-the-latest-mesa-version-on-debian-9-stretch-linux) (mesa 18.0 in my case), since I wanted to be able to use Vulkan with intel hd4400 (Windows doesn't have drivers for it). After installing the mesa drivers and rebooting, not only was via (used to test Vulkan) unable to find said drivers, ROXTerm became invisible in KDE (it's perfectly visible in the tray, it's just that it doesn't render on the screen, however the cursor does change when hovering over it). Is there a way to revert this? Even if it means removing the newer drivers?

P.S: I must probably also mention that I am only used to working with Windows, so I have little to no knowledge about linux, so a detailed answer would be rather helpful. Also, I really don't have the option of changing the linux distribution I have ("modified" Debian 9) - it's the one I am supposed to use from uni.

Comment: what guide ? It's hard to help you here you barely gives us information on what you did.

Comment: @Kiwy: My bad, I had put the wrong link. It should be fixed now.